# Best way to handle a previous session with NextJS for ecommerce

Tags: next.js

Lets say I have an ecommerce site.

Most, if not all of the APIS live on another server.

1. A user puts a couple things in cart
2. signs in, or doesn't
3. Leaves site

come back at a later time.

1. Session fires from cookie, prepopulates cart

What I am confused about is how this can be done sitewide and work with prerendering etc..
I AM NEW TO NEXTJS.

Write now, on my current site, I am just calling the session api. presaturating the redux and then display the page. Standard stuff. curious how this would work with Next and prerendeirng/static generations etc...

Answer (score 1):

Static generations are only available for data that exists at build-time which in this case would exist on request time - therefore you can only achieve pre-rendering via SSR.

From the official documentation:

“You should use getServerSideProps only if you need to pre-render a page whose data must be fetched at request time.”

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/request-time

Comment: Ok cool... so, is there a "proper" way dealing with a users' sesssion (a returning user) when using nextjs and getServerSideProps?